# storing JavaScript dedicated keywords in a variable

Tags: javascript

I am writing some code for my application, when I come across a situation like this:

```
export const trimChar = (string, character, recursive = true) => {
    const func = recursive ? 'while' : 'if'; // <--- Can we do this?
    if (recursive) {
        while (string.charAt(0) === character) {
            string = string.substr(1);
        }
        while (string.charAt(string.length - 1) === character) {
            string = string.substr(0, string.length - 1);
        }
    } else {
        if (string.charAt(0) === character) {
            string = string.substr(1);
        }
        if (string.charAt(string.length - 1) === character) {
            string = string.substr(0, string.length - 1);
        }
    }
    return string;
};
```

You see, when third parameter `recursive` is `false` then two `if` statements are executed, otherwise, two `while` statements are executed. In both cases, body of both `if` & `while` are same.

So, I came across an idea of storing these two dedicated JS keywords in a variable. But this doesn't seems to work. Is there a way we can do this? ***Without using eval***

If not, any suggestions if I can clean up my code? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This simple logic should suffice:

```
export const trimChar = (string, character, recursive = true) => {
    while (string.charAt(0) === character) {
        string = string.substr(1);
        if (!recursive) break;
    }
    while (string.charAt(string.length - 1) === character) {
        string = string.substr(0, string.length - 1);
        if (!recursive) break;
    }
    return string;
};
```

Comment: Yup, that works, but again, what I want to know is if we can store the keywords in a variable, just like we do with dynamic function calling

Comment: You can add the condition to the `if` to avoid using an unnecessary `break`

Comment: @MuhammadWaqar `while` and `if` are operators, not functions. You would end up having to create multiple functions to wrap the appropriate operator usages, which would defeat the purpose of trying to refactor your code to simplify it.